# Changing pymqi over to bindings mode

Tags: python-3.x, pymqi

I have installed `pymqi` on Windows 10 using `pip`:-

```
pip install pymqi
```

I now understand that this locks in the `pymqi` interface to use `mqic` libraries and not `mqm`. According to [this thread from 2018](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/73), the default was going to be changed to use `mqm` libraries, but it would appear that has not yet been done.

That same thread suggests that you can change your already installed `pymqi` to use bindings mode yourself, post install, by running the following command:-

```
python setup.py build server
```

Trouble is, I have no idea where it has put `setup.py` so that I can do this. There doesn't seem to be such a file in my C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pymqi* directories.

If I uninstall it again and re-run the `pip install` command, can I tell it to use bindings mode then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked my question in a more generic way elsewhere, and got an answer that resulted in me being able to answer this question! Yay!

Use the command

```
pip install pymqi --install-option server
```

to install the `pymqi` package tied to using `mqm.lib`